# How do I use the fbtrace_id to find more information?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API often throws errors and mentions you can use the fbtrace_id to find out more information about the error.

Every time I try to use the fbtrace_id, I get another error with a new fbtrace_id. It goes in a circle.

[image: x]
Then I click that and I get this:
[image: y]
And so on.

Comment: _“and mentions you can use the fbtrace_id to find out more information about the error”_ – really, where does it mention that …?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`fbtrace_id` is something you will include when reporting a bug to the Facebook support team.

> fbtrace_id: Internal support identifier. When reporting a bug related to a Graph API call, include the fbtrace_id to help us find log data for debugging.

Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Comment: Would be nice if they exposed a tool to get more information on an error...

Comment: @BenWinding Yeah that should be great, but I don't see that happening since it might reveal information about Facebooks internal systems including security vulnrebillities.